# Join under a Group By condition in Apache Spark

Tags: database, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two DataFrames A and B which look like the following

```
    A: [cust_no,feature1,feature2......]
    B: [ID_number,cust_no]
```

I need to build a DataFrame C

```
    C:[ID_number,feature1,feature2......]
    (where A.cust_no = not any of B.cust_no )**for each ID_number**
```

How do I do this using Apache Spark DataFrame in Scala?

PS: I don't want to extract the ID_numbers and then loop over list of ID_numbers as Apache-Spark doesn't support parallelism among different iterations of *for* loop

Comment: Have you extracted these dataframes from a database with Spark SQL? In this case the best thing to do would probably be to create it directly with Spark SQL otherwise I don't know if it is possible without extracting the ID_numbers.

Comment: @Simon I need to do this  `sqlContext.sql("SELECT A.*,B.ID_number FROM   A LEFT JOIN B  ON A.cust_no= B.cust_no WHERE A.cust_no IS NULL   GROUP BY A.ASIN")`  How do I properly make this ?

Comment: @Simon The data is stored as Part-Files.